# Angular Fetch data using Http Failed to Load

Tags: angular, http

I am new at Angular I am trying to fetch json data but unable to get Console message is= Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

data.service.ts code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
private _url: string = "apidata/mydata.json";
constructor( private _http : Http) {}

getSideNavTitle(){
return this._http.get(this._url)
.map((response:Response) => response.json());
}

testMethod() {
return 'test page or file from the serices file';
}

}
```

service.test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';


const HEROES = [
{id: 1, name:'AAAAA'},
{id: 2, name:'BBBBB'},
 ];

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-service-test',
  templateUrl: './service-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-test.component.css']
 })
export class ServiceTestComponent implements OnInit {
setTitle = [];
heroes = HEROES;
titlepg:string;

constructor(private _exampleService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.titlepg = this._exampleService.testMethod();

 this._exampleService.getSideNavTitle()
 .subscribe(resDataService => this.setTitle = resDataService);

 }
}
```

service-test.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<h1>{{ titlepg }}</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 topic-pad">
  <div class="list-group cour-nav-list">
    <a href="" class="list-group-item active"> First Title </a>
    <a *ngFor="let titleKo of setTitle" href="" class="list-group-item list-
    group-item-action">{{ titleKo.title}}</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and mydata.json is

```
[
{"id": 1, "title":"TitlePart-1"},
{"id": 2, "title":"TitlePart-2"},
{"id": 3, "title":"TitlePart-3"},
{"id": 4, "title":"TitlePart-4"},
{"id": 5, "title":"TitlePart-5"},
{"id": 6, "title":"TitlePart-6"},
{"id": 7, "title":"TitlePart-7"}
]
```

Comment: If you want to load json you need to use server.

Comment: @hurricane can't we fetch data from file ? if not then is there any free server available so that i can try ?

Comment: Yes, you can use "npm install http-server" and "http-server" or create simple nodejs server.

Comment: Yes you can load from file. 404 error means that the file is not found. Try and append the complete "url" starting from top folder (src). If that doesn't work, you probably have an assets folder, try moving it there (which is good practice anyway).

Comment: @hurricane  For to practice can we use free server database like https://www.000webhost.com/

Comment: @Sundar yes you can

Comment: @hurricane can you refer me some article-tutorials or post related to it so that it will be easy for me - i am beginner at Angular so

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have server then it is recommend to us in-memory web API.

Make following modifications to your code

In you app.ts

```
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
  ]

})
```

create new service -

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let yourvar = [
      {"id": 1, "title":"TitlePart-1"},
      {"id": 2, "title":"TitlePart-2"},
      {"id": 3, "title":"TitlePart-3"},
      {"id": 4, "title":"TitlePart-4"},
      {"id": 5, "title":"TitlePart-5"},
      {"id": 6, "title":"TitlePart-6"},
      {"id": 7, "title":"TitlePart-7"}
    ];
    return {titles};
  }
}
```

In your data.service.ts use URL

```
private myurl = 'api/yourvar';
```

Comment: Ya i got some more information from here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html